# Do I need to create a "custom.scss" file when creating a new bootstrap project?

Tags: visual-studio, npm, bootstrap-4

I'm following a Kevin Powell bootstrap tutorial and he copies a custom.scss file into a separate folder, however I can't find that file to copy, not sure if it's because I'm using an updated version of bootstrap.

the bootstrap documentation says after install of bootstrap via npm i should have a folder structure like this:

```
your-project/
├── scss
│   └── custom.scss
└── node_modules/
    └── bootstrap
        ├── js
        └── scss
```

However, upon installing bootstrap into folder it's like this:

```
your-project/
└── node_modules/
    └── bootstrap
        ├── js
        └── scss
```

No scss folder apart from in bootstrap folder.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I ***need*** to create a "custom.scss" file ...?

No you don't ***need*** to do that, as you *could* compile your css directly from the bootstrap source files. However, I would only consider this method if you plan use bootstrap out-of-the-box with no customizations, now or in the future. If you choose not to create this file, then you should probably just use a CDN instead.

### ***Should*** you create a "custom.scss" file?

Yes, this is where you modify bootstrap variables, or extend its components, etc.. You can also choose to import all of bootstrap, or just the parts you need in this file.

The [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#importing) goes over what should be in that file. But you can get started with just the following:

```
// Custom.scss
// Option A: Include all of Bootstrap

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: So i create a file called custom.scss - when i use the above @import. i get an error saying the directory doesn't 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap' exist! Why is it so difficult to get bootstrap environment up and running. I thought it made making website quicker, here I am struggling just to get started. Any recommendations on getting setup faster so i can completely customize bootstrap?

Comment: Try `@import "~/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`